# Create Treemap server-side with jsdom, highcharts

Tags: node.js, svg, charts, server-side, jsdom

I am trying to extract the svg-code from a treemap (type of chart) which is to be generated server-side with nodejs and jsdom.

I have found following code which exports a "line chart" successfully when I run it on my server: https://gist.github.com/TorsteinHonsi/e8a1e6971608523eb8dd

When I change the chart to treemap I get the errors below!

I simply change the code from the line chart to treemap, i.e. i change this

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        forExport: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 400
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

to this (found from official treemap example by highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/treemap-coloraxis/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
     chart: {
        forExport: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 400
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'treemap',
        layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
        data: [{
            name: 'A',
            value: 6,
            colorValue: 1
        }, {
            name: 'B',
            value: 6,
            colorValue: 2
        }, {
            name: 'C',
            value: 4,
            colorValue: 3
        }, {
            name: 'D',
            value: 3,
            colorValue: 4
        }, {
            name: 'E',
            value: 2,
            colorValue: 5
        }, {
            name: 'F',
            value: 2,
            colorValue: 6
        }, {
            name: 'G',
            value: 1,
            colorValue: 7
        }]
    }]
});
```

When I run it with "node myscript.js" I get following errors:

```
/opt/dlins/node-v6.3.0-linux-x64/bin/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:8
(function(D,aa){typeof module==="object"&&module.exports?module.exports=D.document?aa(D):aa:D.Highcharts=aa(D)})(typeof window!=="undefined"?window:this,function(D){function aa(a,b){var c="Highcharts error #"+a+": www.highcharts.com/errors/"+a;if(b)throw Error(c);D.console&&console.log(c)}function pb(a,b,c){this.options=b;this.elem=a;this.prop=c}function E(){var a,b=arguments,c,d={},e=function(a,b){var c,d;typeof a!=="object"&&(a={});for(d in b)b.hasOwnProperty(d)&&(c=b[d],a[d]=c&&typeof c==="object"&&
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ^

Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
    at Error (native)
    at aa (/opt/dlins/node-v6.3.0-linux-x64/bin/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:8:256)
    at Object.gb.initSeries (/opt/dlins/node-v6.3.0-linux-x64/bin/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:214:242)
    at /opt/dlins/node-v6.3.0-linux-x64/bin/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:236:107
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at p (/opt/dlins/node-v6.3.0-linux-x64/bin/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:25:392)
    at Object.gb.firstRender (/opt/dlins/node-v6.3.0-linux-x64/bin/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:236:78)
    at Object.gb.init (/opt/dlins/node-v6.3.0-linux-x64/bin/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:214:135)
    at Object.gb.getArgs (/opt/dlins/node-v6.3.0-linux-x64/bin/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:213:57)
    at Object.x.Chart (/opt/dlins/node-v6.3.0-linux-x64/bin/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.js:212:378)
```

My complete script which produces errors is this:

```js
/**
 * Sample of serverside generation of Highcharts using an extension to jsdom in node.js.
 *
 * Usage: 
 * npm install jsdom
 * npm install highcharts
 * node highcharts-jsdom
 */

/* eslint-env node */
/* eslint no-console: 0 */
var jsdom = require('jsdom'),
    fs = require('fs');

// Get the document and window
var doc = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body><div id="container"></div></body></html>'),
    win = doc.defaultView;

// Do some modifications to the jsdom document in order to get the SVG bounding
// boxes right.
doc.createElementNS = function (ns, tagName) {
    var elem = doc.createElement(tagName);

    // Set private namespace to satisfy jsdom's getter
    elem._namespaceURI = ns; // eslint-disable-line no-underscore-dangle
    /**
     * Pass Highcharts' test for SVG capabilities
     * @returns {undefined}
     */
    elem.createSVGRect = function () {};
    /**
     * jsdom doesn't compute layout (see https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/135).
     * This getBBox implementation provides just enough information to get Highcharts
     * to render text boxes correctly, and is not intended to work like a general
     * getBBox implementation. The height of the boxes are computed from the sum of
     * tspans and their font sizes. The width is based on an average width for each glyph.
     * It could easily be improved to take font-weight into account.
     * For a more exact result we could to create a map over glyph widths for several
     * fonts and sizes, but it may not be necessary for the purpose.
     * @returns {Object} The bounding box
     */
    elem.getBBox = function () {
        var lineWidth = 0,
            width = 0,
            height = 0;

        [].forEach.call(elem.children.length ? elem.children : [elem], function (child) {
            var fontSize = child.style.fontSize || elem.style.fontSize,
                lineHeight,
                textLength;

            // The font size and lineHeight is based on empirical values, copied from
            // the SVGRenderer.fontMetrics function in Highcharts.
            if (/px/.test(fontSize)) {
                fontSize = parseInt(fontSize, 10);
            } else {
                fontSize = /em/.test(fontSize) ? parseFloat(fontSize) * 12 : 12;
            }
            lineHeight = fontSize < 24 ? fontSize + 3 : Math.round(fontSize * 1.2);
            textLength = child.textContent.length * fontSize * 0.55;

            // Tspans on the same line
            if (child.getAttribute('dx') !== '0') {
                height += lineHeight;
            }

            // New line
            if (child.getAttribute('dy') !== null) {
                lineWidth = 0;
            }

            lineWidth += textLength;
            width = Math.max(width, lineWidth);

        });

        return {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: width,
            height: height
        };
    };
    return elem;
};

// Require Highcharts with the window shim
var Highcharts = require('highcharts')(win);

// Disable all animation
Highcharts.setOptions({
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            animation: false,
            dataLabels: {
                defer: false
            }
        }
    }
});

// Generate the chart into the container
/*
// Working simple line chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
  forExport: true,
  width: 600,
  height: 400
 },
 xAxis: {
   categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
  'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
 },
 series: [{
   data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
 }]
});
*/

//not working treemap
// http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/treemap-coloraxis/
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
  forExport: true,
  width: 600,
  height: 400
 },
 series: [{
  type: 'treemap',
  layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
  data: [{
   name: 'A',
   value: 6,
   colorValue: 1
  }, {
   name: 'B',
   value: 6,
   colorValue: 2
  }, {
   name: 'C',
   value: 4,
   colorValue: 3
  }, {
   name: 'D',
   value: 3,
   colorValue: 4
  }, {
   name: 'E',
   value: 2,
   colorValue: 5
  }, {
   name: 'F',
   value: 2,
   colorValue: 6
  }, {
   name: 'G',
   value: 1,
   colorValue: 7
  }]
 }]
});

var svg = win.document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;
fs.writeFile('chart.svg', svg, function () {
    console.log('Wrote ' + svg.length + ' bytes to ' + __dirname + '/chart.svg.'); // eslint-disable-line no-path-concat
});
```

Comment: It looks like you have not added treemap.js module to your project. You can find it on official Highcharts example: <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>

Comment: but I have the whole module loaded via "var Highcharts = require('highcharts')(win);", in the node_modules/highcharts the treemap is present. how can i include it otherwise?

Comment: I think that this problem may be similar to loading modules in this article: http://www.highcharts.com/blog/192-use-highcharts-to-create-charts-in-react

Comment: Haaa! My god it worked when I do require('highcharts/modules/heatmap')(Highcharts); Thanks!!! Been sitting on this for almost 3 days straight

Comment: You're welcome, happy to read it helped in your case :)

Comment: Hej. How would I call the getSVG() on this code, I cannot get it to work. var svg = win.document.getElementById('container').highcharts().getSVG(); It sais " $(...).highcharts is not a function"

Comment: I think that you can add variable chart when you are making you chart: var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options) and then use chart.getSVG().

Answer (score 0):

The Heatmap and Treemap modules needed to be loaded specially.
The library in node_modules does not automatically do that.

Hence two lines of code needed to be added after var Highcharts:

```
require('highcharts/modules/heatmap')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/treemap')(Highcharts);
```